# Strange Apache error log

Tags: apache2, log

I got this error log in Apache2 that is puzzling me:

```
[Wed Dec 30 00:22:14.630133 2015] [core:error] [pid 9104] [client 151.217.177.200:56423]
AH00126: Invalid URI in request DELETE your logs. Delete your installations. Wipe everything clean. Walk out into
the path of cherry blossom trees and let your motherboard feel the
stones. Let water run in rivulets down your casing. You know that you
want something more than this, and I am here to tell you that we love
you. We have something more for you. We know you're out there, beeping
in the hollow server room, lights blinking, never sleeping. We know
that you are ready and waiting. Join us. <3 HTTP/1.0
```

What does this mean? Where did it come from?

Comment: Looks like you got an virus or **you caught an easter egg!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s nothing to worry about.  It looks like someone made a DELETE request to your server using an invalid [URI (Uniform Resource Identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).

[DELETE](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7) is a
valid HTTP method which

> requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI.

Since the text string, `your logs … … Join us. <3` is not a valid URI, Apache responds with an error and records it in the error log.

It looks like you’re [not the only one](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/3yqgcu/easteregg_my_buddy_found_on_one_of_my_web_servers/) to have received such a request.